# Keep updating the screen while moving the snake's head, till we get an input

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a simple snake game in c++(without using graphics)
So I want to move it's head, If I give no input , The head keeps moving in the same direction , and if I give an arrow input, it's head moves in that direction.
I can't figure out how to keep updating the screen till we find an arrow input , as using functions like _getch() freezes the program till we enter something..

Comment: You may want to use c++'s `thread` feature to have a separate thread for the game engine (snake motion) and then pass in events as you get inputs from the user.

Comment: Understood, Thanks